# Sorting with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, sorting, xslt-1.0

**UPDATE - New code at the bottom**

I'm trying to figure out how to use the sort function to pull the most recent record from some XML data.  I'm very new to using XSLT and am running into a bunch of problems. Here's an example of my data...

```
<content date="1/13/2011 1:21:00 PM">
    <collection vo="promotion">
        <data vo="promotion" promotionid="64526" code="101P031" startdate="1/7/2011 12:00:00 AM"/>
        <data vo="promotion" promotionid="64646" code="101P046" startdate="1/9/2011 12:00:00 AM"/>
    </collection>
</content>
```

What I want to do is sort the data by promotionid in decsending order and then ONLY ouput via HTML the promotionid that is greatest.  Here is along the lines of what I was trying

**UPDATE - This is the latest version of the code that is still experiencing problems.**

```
<html><body>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"  encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:template match="content/collection/data">
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:sort select="promotionid" order="descending" data-type="number" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="content/collection">
        <xsl:value-of select="data/@promotionid" />
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
</body></html>
```

While this does return results what I am getting back is '64526' and NOT '64646'.

Can anyone help?  Also I've seen examples online where you can sort by multiple fields.  It may be worth noting now, rather then asking later, that we may want to end up sorting by startdate rather than promotionid.  I have managed to come up with code to break out the date by YYYY, MM, and DD, but have no idea how I would even begin to use that aside from using those as my select paramater of the sort, but I don't know if that actually works or not.

```
Year
<xsl:value-of select="substring(substring-after(substring-after(data/@startdate,'/'),'/'),1,4)" />

Month
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(data/@startdate,'/')" />

Day
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(data/@startdate,'/'),'/')" />
```

Thank in advance and I appologize my less than novice XSLT skills.

**------------------------------------------------------**

After some help here the code has changed, but is still not working as intended.  Here is the code...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"  encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:template match="content/collection/">
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort select="@promotionid" order="descending" data-type="number" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="content/collection/data">
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                   <xsl:value-of select="@promotionid"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And I am still seeing the lesser value ouput rather than the greater.  Perhaps there is another way to do this with out sorting?  As I am open to that possibility as well.

**1/14/11 10:37 Update**
**-------------------------------------------------------------------**
Okay using this code now does indeed sort the data and output the highest promotionid number.  Thanks a Ton!

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="collection">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="data">
         <xsl:sort select="@promotionid" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="content/collection/data">
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                   <xsl:value-of select="@promotionid"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Ignoring the promtionid now can you show me how I would sort, descending, by JUST the date?  I tried removing Unfortunately I know the dates should have a static length, but we have no control of the data we receive :-(

Also can you recommend a book to start with to really can some better understanding of all this?  You've been a tremendous help!

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the cause of your problem and for example of sorting on multiple kes, as well for a recommendation abot the date format you are using.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:sort select="promotionid" order="descending" data-type="number"
> ```
>
> />

**There is an obvious error here**: `promotionid` is an attribute, not an element.

**Solution**:

```
select="@promotionid" order="descending" data-type="number" />
```

**Another error**:

```
<xsl:template match="content/collection/data">
    <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:sort select="promotionid" order="descending" data-type="number" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

The `<xsl:apply-templates>` and sorting is performed too-late.

**You want**:

```
<xsl:template match="content/collection/">
            <xsl:apply-templates>
                <xsl:sort select="@promotionid" order="descending" data-type="number" />
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:template>
```

**and**

```
    <xsl:template match="content/collection/data">
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                   <xsl:value-of select="@promotionid"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

**As for your expanded question**:

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="collection">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="data">
         <xsl:sort select="@promotionid" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
         <xsl:sort select=
          "concat(
             substring-after(substring-after(substring-before(@startdate,' ')
                                             ,'/'
                                             ),
                               '/'
                               ),
             substring-before(substring-after(substring-before(@startdate,' ')
                                             ,'/'
                                             ),
                              '/'
                            ),
             substring-before(substring-after(substring-before(@startdate,' ')
                                             ,'/'
                                             ),
                               '/'
                               )
                )"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to the provided XML document**:

```
<content date="1/13/2011 1:21:00 PM">
    <collection vo="promotion">
        <data vo="promotion" promotionid="64526" code="101P031" startdate="1/7/2011 12:00:00 AM"/>
        <data vo="promotion" promotionid="64646" code="101P046" startdate="1/9/2011 12:00:00 AM"/>
    </collection>
</content>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<content date="1/13/2011 1:21:00 PM">

   <collection vo="promotion">
      <data vo="promotion" promotionid="64646" code="101P046" startdate="1/9/2011 12:00:00 AM"/>
      <data vo="promotion" promotionid="64526" code="101P031" startdate="1/7/2011 12:00:00 AM"/>
   </collection>

</content>
```

**However, note** that this well not handle the variable length for the date components. It is better to use fixed length format: mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: Hi Dimitre, thanks for your help. I haven't tested the multi-sort question, but am going examine it closely later.  In regards to solution to the first half of my question it still doesn't appear to be working.  I changed the select in the sort to add the '@' but the resulting output is still 64526

Comment: @dscl: Yes, there are also other errors in your code -- see my updated reply.

Comment: @dimitre Hi again, I tried the update you listed above and am still seeing the wrong result.  I've uploaded the code here http://snipplr.com/view/47119/sort/  Note, I tried the select with the @ and without since your original message said it was lacking, but the update also did not include it.

Comment: @dscl: Yes, I had just copied/pasted your code -- it is reflected now. As for the inability still to get the wanted result, you may have yet other problems. Why dont you edit your question with the complete latest code, so that I will be able to try and repro your problem?

Comment: @dimitre-novatchev : I've updated my original post with the current code at the bottom, per your suggestion, because I am still not seeing the correct value.

Comment: @dscl: Just copy and paste my code and apply this transformation to your provided XML document. You must get the same results as I do. In case you don't, then you have either a copy/paste error, or your XSLT processor is buggy. I always verify that my solutions work. In this case my transformation produces the same correct result with 7 different XSLT 1.0 processors: MSXML (3,4 and 6) .NET (XslCompiledTransform and XslTransform), XmlSPY and Saxon 6.5.5

Comment: @dimitre-novatchev:  You have been a tremendous help. 2 follow up questions added to the bottom of the original post.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: @dscl: Don't you think that the "question" has become "many questions"? Please, ask them as separate questions -- this would be a great service to other SO readers trying to find a particular problem. Also, you may not be aware that at SO the established way of saying "Thank you" is to accept the answer?

Comment: @dimitre-novatchev: Answer accepted and a new question posted -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4694204/xslt-1-0-sorting-by-concating-portions-of-date-string